# Adding a selector to a jQuery object in function parameter

Tags: jquery, function, selector, arguments

Sorry for the subject line, but I wasn't sure how exactly to phrase it. I'd like to automate this to a function `$('#progress-row-1 .indicator).css('width', 100);` the following way:

```
setWidth($('#progress-row-1'), 100);
```

So I only pass the ID of the element to the function. The element has only one child with a class called ".indicator". So...

In the function, I'd like to set the CSS width of the element who has a class named "indicator":

```
function setWidth(obj, size) {
    $('obj .indicator').css('width', size);
}
```

I know the `$('obj .indicator')` syntax is wrong, but I don't know what is the correct one. How would I access the passed object's child who has a class named ".indicator" such way? Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find()`

```
obj.find(".indicator").css('width', size);
```

Answer (score 3):

Turning it into a plugin method:

```
$.fn.setIndicatorWidth=function(width){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).find('.indicator').width(width);
    });
}
```

Useage:

```
$('#progress-row-1').setIndicatorWidth(100);
```

Comment: bruv ++1 Yes please `.width`. `:)`

Comment: I like it, however, for the sake of argument, isn't this functionality a bit narrow in scope for a plugin? Genuinely curious about people's opinions on that.

Comment: @BLSully why too narrow, it keep's code readable in jQuery syntax and is chainable

Comment: @charlietfl: Admittedly I don't know what the OP is trying to achieve, but this seems like something that either should be packaged at a higher level as a widget (theory is the end result here is a progress bar based on the id/class names), or is too infrequently used to hardcode things like the class-name inside the function.

Comment: @BLSully  really not sure what you are suggesting. OP wants a function separated from the call, so likely plans on reusing it so plugin makes as much sense as regular function

Comment: @charlietfl: Fair enough. Your answer just surprised me and got me thinking. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2):

The most concise syntax (and I believe fastest) solution for that would be:

```
$('.indicator', obj).css('width', size);
```